What block cipher should I use for encrypting GCM initialization vector counter-based nonce?
I'm implementing a mobile VPN product based on AES-GCM that should be resistant against fingerprinting the movements of mobile nodes. A difficulty is that the mobile nodes may not have the best possible random number generators, so a random nonce for each packet might not be the most secure way. Also, the mathematics of the birthday attack do not favor random nonces: only about 1014 random 96-bits nonces can be created until there is large likelihood of collision. On the other hand, 264 is over 1019, so even a 64-bit counter would be superior to a random 96-bit nonce.
It is extremely unlikely that a node could generate more than 264 packets in its lifetime, so I had a bright idea: each node has an initialization vector key, a counter, and they use a block cipher to create the 64 bits of the nonce by encrypting the counter. Because a block cipher is reversible, if the inputs to it are never duplicated, its outputs are never duplicated. Only one crypto operation on a single 64-bit block is needed per packet, which shouldn't reduce performance much (since packets are typically 8000 bits or so, meaning that with AES-GCM quite many crypto operations are needed per packet anyway).
Ideally I would like to have a block size of more than 64 bits but less than 96 bits (since I'm using one bit for direction indicator), but it seems such ciphers are very rare: Rijndael has to have a block size with a multiple of 32 bits, so it's either 64 or 96 bits (96 bits is too large for my use case by a whopping 1 bit).
A counter-based nonce without block cipher encrypting it won't do, since an attacker might memoize the value of the counter of each device, and track their movements.
The question is, what cipher should I use for this nonce generation?
At least some notable block ciphers with a block size of 64 bits are:

DES: no way am I going to use it
triple DES: sounds like a hack and is slow
IDEA: I haven't heard much of this recently, not sure why
Blowfish
Rijndael with a 64-bit block size: might not be as thoroughly analyzed with a 64-bit block size as it's with 128-bit block size, since AES uses 128 bits, also might be hard to find good implementations with a 64-bit block size

Currently I'm leaning towards Blowfish, but I'm still open to using Rijndael if it's significantly more secure even with a block size of 64 bits and good implementations can be found.
Note this cipher wouldn't be used to encrypt actual data, only create the nonce, so a break of it would only allow fingerprinting of movements, not decryption of the actual network packets.
Of course, if an attacker sees two devices using the same nonce even once, the attacker knows they can't be the same device, so perfect protection against fingerprinting the movements cannot be achieved.

What about using xChaCha20-Poly1305 to eliminate nonce collision with 192-bit nonce/IV sizes?

If you are not going to generate $2^{64}$ packets, then how likely is it that you're going to generate $2^{63}$ packets? And if you're going to use the block cipher to obscure a counter and use the result instead of the counter itself, then you don't need to reverse and you can use any PRP (such as AES) or PRF (a MAC) and then take the leftmost bits (I wrote hash algorithm too, but you'd want to create a PRF out of that, so then it is not much of an extra option). Preferably you'd use a different key or otherwise make sure that you don't collide the output of AES with AES-GCM.

ChaCha20-Poly1305 would otherwise be fine, but it lacks hardware acceleration.

@MaartenBodewes I don't think this would work. PRF is not collision free and 2^95 bits of data have one collision in about 2^47.5 packets, whereas with block cipher, 2^64 packets are guaranteed to have no collisions. Taking the leftmost bits also introduces collisions, making it likely to have a collision in 2^47.5 packets, but if the function can be reversed (like a block cipher), it's guaranteed to be collision-free in first 2^64 packets if the block size is 64 bits.

The advantage is over NI and around two times the speed advantage. The ChaCha series is designed to be CPU friendly.
